# Error when i'm creating new sql view in geoserver : function wrk_fromatob() does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geoserver, pgrouting

hellow, I'm learning to create a **routing application** with this new [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/index.html). This is using Postgres as the database, and its extensions PostGIS and pgRouting. It uses GeoServer to manage data and publish that.

I got data from osm and then added it to database with osm2pgrouting to be able to use them. After that I installed geoserver too then created a layer for my data but when I try to create new SQL view I get this error:

> ERROR: function wrk_fromatob(unknown, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 76

I searched a lot but I can't find any answer.

Comment: The function could be in a schema that is not in your current `search_path`. You could be connected to a different database. You could be connected as a user that does not have permissions on the function or the schema that contains it.

Comment: thanks so much, I found out that i forgot a function to add to database. i will post answer for my question soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to create **wrk_fromatob()** function in my database. so there is the answer on this part of workshop: [Writing a pl/pgsql Stored Procedures](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/chapters/function.html) .